# how to use xpath with a namespace in Postgres?

Tags: xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

I am having some issues with `xpath()`. Consider the example XML below:

```
<data code = '123' platform = 'a' xmlns = "http://www.myexample.com" >
 <payload>
   <title> this is it! </title>
 </payload>
</data>
```

This is what is stored in my column `xml` in the database. I am simply trying to retrieve the `this is it!` text. I have tried many different queries (I think the issue might be the namespace), nothing works.

For instance:

```
select *, xpath('//my:payload/text()',
                xml::xml,
                ARRAY[ARRAY['my','http://www.myexample.com']]) from mydatabase
```

returns nothing. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `mydatabases` is  strange name for a **table**

Comment: its an example :) . any idea? thanks

Comment: The text is in the tag `title`, not `payload` , therefor you need `'//my:payload/my:title/text()'` as the xpath

Comment: thanks but that still returns an empty result...

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/tqa1o1B_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for return data from XML i use `xmltable`

```
select *
from T
  cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://www.myexample.com' as m),
                      '/m:data/m:payload' 
                      passing cast(xml_column as xml)
                      columns title text path 'm:title'
                      ) as x
```

Comment: it seems I cannot use xmltable... only xpath seems to work

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ then you are either using an outdated (unsupported) Postgres version or not using Postgres at all.